# How to deduct margin left using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi all I need deduct `css` margin using jquery I have this script please help me I need deduct `200 px` `var mergin = $(this).css("left") - 200;` but not work

```
$(this).find('.circle').click(function(){
    var margin = $(this).css("left");
    $('.move_plane').animate({marginLeft:margin});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need only this script

```
var margin = parseInt( $(this).css("left")) - 200;
enter code here
```

Comment: You have forget _radix_ param in `parseInt` function

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your margin value to `Integer`:

```
var margin = parseInt( $(this).css("left"), 10 );
```

Comment: `var margin = parseInt( $(this).css("left")) - 200;`

Comment: @valkharitonashvili don't forget _radix_ param: `var margin = parseInt( $(this).css("left"), 10) - 200;`

Comment: please tell me what is `radix`  value I don't know :)

Comment: @valkharitonashvili you can read about `radix` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
$(this).css('left', "-=200");
```

or possibly:

```
$(this).css('marginLeft', "-=200");
```

or maybe just skip that step:

```
$('.move_plane').animate({'marginLeft': '-=200'});
```

Without a full example of your code, including HTML and CSS, it's hard to tell what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the `$(this).css("left")` will give you value along with the scales like *px ,pt, em* as wat you set. so get the integer value out of the value and -200 then append the *px* then set it back.